# Fn keys can't adjust brightness MATE desktop

Tags: 14.04, brightness, mate

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and removed Unity and installed MATE. Now, the Fn keys on my keyboard can't adjust brightness. Here's the thing that makes it extra extr confusing: my brightness worked under Unity. Even more confusing, there is a bug in MATE that makes a small white square appear. I don't see it. It's like when I press my brightness keys, nothing happens like I'm not even pressing them. This worked under Unity.

Comment: Also, I'm not using a version of Ubuntu MATE or anything, I installed the packages myself from official PPAs and the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Is there a package that is responsible for the brightness? maybe I need to install it.

Comment: Okay. If no one wants to give me an answer, at least tell me of a program I can use to adjust my brightness. A command would do nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is MATE does not come with a program to manage brightness. In a terminal, type `sudo apt-get install mate-power-manager` and let it install. Restart, and brightness should now work because there is a program to handle brightness key presses.